# Preserving formatting (\t) in scraped text - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a program that takes the text from a website using this following code:

```
import selenium
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"\chromedriver.exe")
   
def get_raw_input(link_input, website_input, driver): 
    driver.get(f'{website_input}')
    try:
        here_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/h3/a')
        here_button.click()
        raw_data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/pre').text
    except:
        move_on = False
        while move_on == False:
            try:
                raw_data = driver.find_element_by_class_name('output').text
                move_on == True
            except:
                pass
    driver.close()
    return raw_data
```

the section of text it is targeting,is formatted like so

> englishword *tab* frenchword

however, the return I get is in this format:

> englishword *space* frenchword

the english part of the text could be a phrase with spaces in it, I cannot simply `.split(" ")` since it may split the phrase as well.

My end goal is to keep the formatting using *tab* instead of *space* so I can `.split("\t")` to make things easier for later manipulation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Show HTML of that `pre` node

Comment: @JaSON <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium returns element text in the way how browser renders it. So it typically "normalizes" whitespaces (all inner space symbols turn into a single space).

You can see some discussion [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2608). The solution to get the actually spaced text suggested by Selenium guys is to query `textContent` property from element.

Here is the example:

```py
raw_data = driver.find_element_by_class_name('output').get_property('textContent')
```

Comment: I am struggling to find the textContent attribute within the element. The HTML I have is now in the question

Comment: Try to apply my example